# Enable HTTP2 with Tomcat in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, http, spring-mvc

We have some legacy `Spring MVC` based application at our organization. They current use `HTTP 1`. We plane to improve performance by upgrading them to `HTTP 2` protocol.

These MVC applications have following configurations

- Tomcat 8.5
- Spring MVC 4

Unable to find any online help for upgrading to `HTTP 2` from `HTTP 1`

Also if the community can suggest for any typical challenge/issue which could arise out of this upgrade (though I have checked that it holds backward compatibility)

---

With Spring boot it is a relatively easier affair where we can do below mentioned changes, but unable to solve this for Spring MVC

```
server.http2.enabled=true
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set the config in Spring Boot, all it does it set some configuration in Tomcat (or whatever server it's configured to use).

The relevant docs for the Tomcat config are:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html#HTTP/2_Support
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http2.html

Comment: with spring boot ..its an easy cake. I faced issue with Spring MVC.

Comment: My point being, that Spring Boot is just a thin layer on top of the other Spring libraries, plus an optional server and that it's just providing a convenience. With Spring MVC you don't have that convenience and so you need to do the config manually, by referring to the documentation above.